# Can you cyclicly permutate the indices of the spatial derivative of the metric tensor?

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems

I am working on an exercise in general relativity and it would be very convenient if
$$
\frac{\partial g_{\sigma \nu}}{\partial x^\kappa} 
= 
\frac{\partial g_{\nu \kappa}}{\partial x^\sigma} 
$$

where $g_{\sigma \nu}$ is the metric tensor.

Is this identitiy true/false and how would you prove it?

Answer (score 3):

In general it's false.  In comoving coordinates on FLRW spacetime, the metric is

$$\mathrm ds^2 = -c^2 \mathrm dt^2 + a(t)^2 (\mathrm dx^2 + \mathrm dy^2 + \mathrm dz^2)$$
It's easy to see that e.g. $\partial_0 g_{11} \neq \partial_1 g_{01}$.